# Regex Matches In Array (Convert from JS to C#)

Tags: javascript, c#

I'm currently experimenting with C#, trying to rewrite a JS app as a console app.

In JS I currently store my regex patterns as such :

```
var replacements = [
    // Variables
    {'k': /@((?!media|include|charset|document|font-face|import|keyframes|page|supports)[a-zA-Z_]+)/g, 'v': '$$$1'},
    // Extends
    {'k': /@include(\W+[.#][^(;]*;)/g, 'v': '@extend$1'},
    // Mixins
    {'k': /\.([\w\-]*)\s*\((.*)\)\s*\{/g, 'v': '@mixin $1\($2\)\n{'},
    // Includes
    {'k': /\.([\w\-]*\(.*\)\s*;)/g, 'v': '@include $1'},
    // String literals
    {'k': /~"(.*)"/g, 'v': '#{"$1"}'},
    // Spin does not exist in sass
    {'k': /spin\(/g, 'v': 'adjust-hue('},
];
```

I think iterate of these as such :

```
for (var i = 0; i < replacements.length; i++) {
        text = text.replace(replacements[i].k, replacements[i].v);
    }
```

My question is, how can I create the replacements var above, in C#?

Any direction or assistance would be much appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: You can create a list of key value pair

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help, are you able to provide an example please? I'm very new to C# and trying to learn as I go.